# adding a css inside a link_to do function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make link_to function have a css class attached to it,

My code is something like this:

```
<%= link_to newGame do%>
<%= image_tag newGame.image_url.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

which links an image to its content, but I need to add a class="thumbnail" to the link,

ie:

```
<a href="/games/:id" class="thumbnaill>
```

instead of what its currently generating:

```
<a href="/games/:id">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002140)

```
<%= link_to newGame, class: 'thumbnail'  do %>
```

Be careful when using the older argument style, as an extra literal hash is needed:

```
<%= link_to "Articles", { :controller => "articles" }, :id => "news", :class => "article" %>
#Gives <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
<%= link_to newGame, class: 'thumbnail' do %>
  <%= image_tag newGame.image_url.to_s %>
<% end %>
```